# Взять id нужно элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как при нажатии на `input id="id[1]"` показать `value input class="id[1]"`, а при нажатии на второй input следовательно value второго inputa.

```js
function showMessage() {
var id = document.getElementsByClassName('id').value;
  alert( id );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id[1]" type="text" onclick="showMessage()">
<input class="id[1]" type="hidden" value="25">
<input id=id[2] type="text" onclick="showMessage()">
<input class="id[2]" type="hidden" value="35">
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName коллекцию  и у него нет value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("input[id^='id'").click(function(){
  var id=$(this).attr('id');
  var value=$(`input[class='${id}']`).val();
  alert(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id[1]" type="text">
<input class="id[1]" type="hidden" value="25">
<input id=id[2] type="text">
<input class="id[2]" type="hidden" value="35">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("input").on("click", function() {
  var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
  console.log($(`input[class='${inputId}']`).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id[1]" type="text">
<input class="id[1]" type="hidden" value="25">
<input id=id[2] type="text">
<input class="id[2]" type="hidden" value="35">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function showMessage(element) {
  let input = document.getElementsByClassName(element.id)[0];
  alert(input.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="id[1]" type="text" onclick="showMessage(this)">
<input class="id[1]" type="hidden" value="25">
<input id=id[2] type="text" onclick="showMessage(this)">
<input class="id[2]" type="hidden" value="35">
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном подходе две ошибки:

1. [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает **коллекцию** элементов, а у коллекции нет свойства value
2. В разметке нет элементов с классом `id`.

---

Для получении в обработчике элемента по которому кликнули, можно передать его в качестве параметра:

```
<input id="id[1]" type="text" onclick="showMessage(this)">
```

Далее, добавить параметр в определении обработчика

```
function showMessage(el) {
```

После этого, у полученного элемента можно взять свойство `id`

```
el.id
```

И, так как, судя по всему, элемент должен быть один, лучше воспользоваться функцией [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), однако тут придется экранировать скобки.

Пример:

```js
function showMessage(el) {
  var val = document.querySelector(
    '.' + el.id.replace(/(\[|\])/g, "\\$1")).value;
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id[1]" type="text" onclick="showMessage(this)">
<input class="id[1]" type="hidden" value="25">
<input id=id[2] type="text" onclick="showMessage(this)">
<input class="id[2]" type="hidden" value="35">
```

---

Можно также оставить использование [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) однако в этом случае придется выбирать конкретный элемент из коллекции:

```js
function showMessage(el) {
  var val = document.getElementsByClassName(el.id)[0].value;
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id[1]" type="text" onclick="showMessage(this)">
<input class="id[1]" type="hidden" value="25">
<input id=id[2] type="text" onclick="showMessage(this)">
<input class="id[2]" type="hidden" value="35">
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function showMessage(className) {
  var id = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].value;
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<input id="id[1]" type="text" onclick="showMessage('id[2]')">
<input class="id[1]" type="hidden" value="25">
<input id=id[2] type="text" onclick="showMessage('id[1]')">
<input class="id[2]" type="hidden" value="35">
```

Comment: Будет всегда возвращать значение с одного и того же input

Comment: не проблема просто передавть имя класса